# Are null values in QueryBuilder join conditions handled automatically?

Tags: typeorm

I'm using:

- typeorm = 0.2.7
- pg = 7.4.3
- PostgreSQL = 9.6

For Repository.find() it seems there is some support for automatically turning null values in where conditions into "IS NULL" clauses in the generated SQL. Is this also done for inner join conditions?

Asked a different way, should the following work?

```
userRepo.createQueryBuilder('user')
  .innerJoin(
    'user.phone',
    'phone',
    'phone.type = :type',
    { type: null }
  )
  .getMany();
```

From the debugging I've done so far, it seems to generate "phone.type = $X", and the query doesn't retrieve the expected results.